# Syntax error with PHP script from Essential Grid that shows "Sold out" badges in WooCommerce

Tags: php, syntax, grid

I am trying to put into my WooCommerce e-shop badges for products that are sold out.

Plugins are available, but I am using the Essential Grid plugin to display products (so classic plugins are off the table).

There is a solution for that ([described here](https://www.essential-grid.com/faq/display-woocommerce-product-stock-status-on-essential-grid/)), directly from Essential Grid developers, but it (apparently) contains a syntax error at line 15 described like this:

`$html = ‘<p class=”stock in-stock”>In stock</p>’;`

The whole code is listed below.

Since I am a complete newbie to PHP, I would appreciate a fix of that code so I can use it. Can anyone please help? ;)

```
add_shortcode( ‘stock_status’, ‘display_product_stock_status’ );

function display_product_stock_status( $atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(‘id’  => get_the_ID() ),
        $atts, ‘stock_status’
    );
 
if( intval( $atts[‘id’] ) > 0 && function_exists( ‘wc_get_product’ ) ){
    $product = wc_get_product( $atts[‘id’] );
 
    $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
 
    if ( ‘instock’ == $stock_status) {        
$html = ‘<p class=”stock in-stock”>In stock</p>’;  
    } else {
$html = ‘<p class=”stock out-of-stock”>Out of stock</p>’;      
    }
}
return $html;
}
```

I tried to find out how to fix the syntax error, but since I don't understand PHP grammar, I was not able to resolve it.

Comment: You have the wrong types of quotes in your code. You need to use straight quotes, not curly quotes. Use a proper code editor, or turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems their example is using "smart" quotes. Just replace them with regular straight single and double quotes:

```php
add_shortcode( 'stock_status', 'display_product_stock_status' );

function display_product_stock_status( $atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array('id'  => get_the_ID() ),
        $atts, 'stock_status'
    );
 
    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
    
        $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
    
        if ( 'instock' == $stock_status) {        
            $html = '<p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>';  
        } else {
            $html = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock</p>';      
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```